# How can I get at the file version info of a file when running Delphi on Android?

Tags: android, delphi, getfileversion

I'm using Delphi XE7 and I want to log some info about my app to a log file, so I need to port over the GetFileVersionInfo in MSWindows to work in Android. If possible I'd like a general routine that works for any file. I see that there is a Delphi example of [how to get file version info in OSX here](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2012/12/08/retrieving-the-applications-version-string/), but I cant find anything that points me to the relevant Android unit. Can anyone help please?

Comment: What kind of version info would Android provide for the files my app creates?

Comment: @greenapps: Take a look at your project options 'Version Info'. For Windows, that stuffs version info into the project exe. For Android, it is similar. I don't know where the version info goes, but hey - who cares!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a quick example:

```
uses
  ...
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNI.App,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.NativeActivity;

function GetPackageInfo: JPackageInfo;
var
  Activity: JActivity;
begin
  Activity := TJNativeActivity.Wrap(PANativeActivity(System.DelphiActivity)^.clazz);
  Result := Activity.getPackageManager.getPackageInfo(Activity.getPackageName, 0);
end;

procedure TPForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Info: JPackageInfo;
begin
  Info := GetPackageInfo;
  Label1.Text := Format('versionName: "%s", versionCode: %d', [JStringToString(Info.versionName), Info.versionCode]);
end;
```

Comment: You're the man! Perfect thanks. So perfect in fact that I don't suppose you have sample code for accessing Hardware.USB...?!